# Video file size for web use

Tags: video, compression

What is the best video size for let's say a 5 minute video. I want to host my own videos. So, I want to understand more.

What is an acceptable size?

Comment: Why not have a look at youtube's specs for a ballpark? Then test it on your server on a variety of devices and locations. http://bit.ly/1NNxDhX

Comment: @stib Why not converting this into an answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compress videos for a website?](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16361/how-to-compress-videos-for-a-website)

Answer (score 1):

First off, why host your own videos? YouTube, Vimeo and many others have awesome embed tools, and unless you have a couple of GB to waste on your host, they're very practical.

But to your question, 1080x720 is perfectly fine, and creates a reasonable file size. 1920x1080 is pushing it a little, and 4K is just overkill.

I'm a web developer too, and when I have to host videos for a live background, featured video, etc, 1080x720 is my go to resolution, and I host things of larger size on YouTube since they'll take something like a 4K video, and give viewers the option of a resolution as low as 360p.

Answer (score 0):

I would analyze how YouTube encodes videos, as described in [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/16361/3481). It also helps you to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Someone removed our close votes, but I don't understand why downvoted your answer then... Anyway,  removed my comment and upvoted the answer! :)